# DNS works only with ip but does not work with NS CentOS + Bind9

Tags: networking, dns, centos, bind

I am having a headache with DNS.

Lets say my public IP is 1.2.3.4, my local IP is 192.168.0.10 and my domain is example.com
I am running CentOS on a virtual machine (Parallels Desktop for Mac) with a LAN card reserved for it, so it gets Ip directly from the router. I have ports 80,443,53 forwarded to 192.168.0.10. Both Mac OS and CentOs firewalls are Off.

The strange is when I type
**dig @1.2.3.4 example.com** from my other PC I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @1.2.3.4 example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16941
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        86400   IN  A   1.2.3.4

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns2.example.com.
example.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns1.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.com.        86400   IN  A   1.2.3.4
ns2.example.com.        86400   IN  A   1.2.3.4

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 1.2.3.4#53(1.2.3.4)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov  2 09:37:36 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 109
```

but when i type: **dig @ns1.example.com example.com** it waits a few seconds and returns **dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.dsht.in': not found**

This is my config file:
/etc/named.conf

```
options {
    listen-on-v6 { none; };

    directory"/var/named";
    dump-file"/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file"/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file"/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";

    allow-query{ localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; };
    allow-transfer { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

# change all from here
view "internal" {
        match-clients {
                localhost;
                192.168.0.0/24;
        };
        zone "." IN {
                type hint;
                file "named.ca";
        };
        zone "example.com" IN {
                type master;
                file "example.com.zone";
                allow-update { none; };
        };
        zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
                type master;
                file "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
                allow-update { none; };
        };
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
};
view "external" {
        match-clients { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
        recursion no;
        zone "example.com" IN {
                type master;
                file "example.com.zone";
                allow-update { none; };
        };
        zone "4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa" IN {
                type master;
                file "4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa";
                allow-update { none; };
        };
};
```

/var/named/exmaple.com.zone

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.example.com. host.example.com. (
        2013042201  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
; Specify our two nameservers
        IN  NS      ns1.example.com.
        IN  NS      ns2.example.com.
; Resolve nameserver hostnames to IP, replace with your two droplet IP addresses.
ns1     IN  A       1.2.3.4
ns2     IN  A       1.2.3.4

; Define hostname -> IP pairs which you wish to resolve
@       IN  A       1.2.3.4
        IN  A       1.2.3.4
www     IN  A       1.2.3.4
server2 IN  A   192.168.0.2
*       IN  A       1.2.3.4
```

/var/named/4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa

```
$TTL 2d  ; 172800 seconds
$ORIGIN 4.3.2.1.IN-ADDR.ARPA.
@             IN      SOA   ns1.example.com. host.example.com. (
                              2013010304 ; serial number
                              3h         ; refresh
                              15m        ; update retry
                              3w         ; expiry
                              3h         ; nx = nxdomain ttl
                              )
              IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
              IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
              IN      PTR     example.com.
; etc
```

/var/named/0.168.192.in-addr.arpa

```
$TTL 2d  ; 172800 seconds
$ORIGIN 0.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.
@             IN      SOA   ns1.example.com. host.example.com. (
                              2013010304 ; serial number
                              3h         ; refresh
                              15m        ; update retry
                              3w         ; expiry
                              3h         ; nx = nxdomain ttl
                              )
              IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
              IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
10            IN      PTR     example.com.
2         IN      PTR     server2.example.com
; etc
```

I will be very glad if someone can help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf from the remote PC and the NS.    and do you have IPv6 on the CentOS box from your ISP?

Comment: Is ns1.dsht.in your example.com?

Comment: Do you have IPv6 on the CentOS box or remote PC from your ISP?